# Make all non-null values in a row unique

Tags: sql, postgresql, check-constraints

I have a table with the following columns: id, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6.

Constraint says that there is a minimum of 3 columns filled (so up to 3 NULLs). (columns are filled not in order, so there can be col1, col2, col5 filled and col3, col4, col6 are NULLs)

How do I ensure that when the column is not NULL, it is unique across other columns in this row?
How do I ensure that the combination of non-NULL values is unique across all rows?

I currently added the following constraint (to ensure the at least 3 non-nulls):

```
  ALTER TABLE my_table
    ADD CONSTRAINT my_constraint CHECK (
      (
        (CASE WHEN col1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) +
        (CASE WHEN col2 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) +
        (CASE WHEN col3 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) +
        (CASE WHEN col4 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) +
        (CASE WHEN col5 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) +
        (CASE WHEN col6 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
      ) >= 3
    )
```

Comment: My first reaction here is that you might want to change your table design.  Instead of having six columns, just have a single column, along with a second column to keep track of the original "column."

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am afraid I did not understand your point

Comment: Have a check constraint that adds 1 for each non-null column, and verify that the sum is at least 3.

Comment: @jarlh But what about the unique requirement?  That is something for aggregation across _rows_, not columns.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, oops, missed that part.

Comment: Uniqueness across all rows would be guaranteed by a single unique constraint over all columns.

Comment: What data type are those columns?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name col1,col2... are all varchar columns

Comment: If you say the "combination of non-NULL values should be unique". Do you mean that if one row has `col1 = 'A', col2 = 'B'` and another has `col5 = 'B' and `col6 = `A'` these should be considered the same?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, according to business logic these two rows would have identical set of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell these are actually three different constraints. The one that at least three non-null values have to be present is easy:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
   ADD CONSTRAINT my_constraint CHECK ( num_nonnulls(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6) >= 3);
```

The requirement that no duplicate values should be present in the 6 columns of a single row can be done by create a function that checks this:

```
create or replace function all_unique(p_row my_table)
  returns boolean
as
$$
  select not exists (
    select v
    from (
        values (p_row.c1), (p_row.c2), (p_row.c3), (p_row.c4), (p_row.c5), (p_row.c6)
    ) t(v)
    where v is not null
    group by v
    having count(*) > 1);
$$
language sql
immutable
strict;
```

The function returns true if all non-null values are unique within a single row. I defined it to receive a complete row, so that it' easier to adapt if new columns are added or removed. I am not sure if that is the most efficient or simplest way of doing that, but I can't think of something else right now.

This can be used for a check constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
    ADD CONSTRAINT all_unique CHECK ( all_unique(my_table) );
```

And the final requirement that the non-null values should be unique across multiple rows can be implemented with a unique index. But for that we need a function that creates an array of the non-null values in a sorted fashion:

```
create or replace function non_null_values(p_row my_table)
  returns text[]
as
$$
  select array(
    select distinct v
    from (
        values (p_row.c1), (p_row.c2), (p_row.c3), (p_row.c4), (p_row.c5), (p_row.c6)
    ) t(v)
    where v is not null
    order by v);
$$
language sql
immutable
strict;
```

Why does it have to be sorted? Because the array `[1,2,3]` is not considered equal (`=`) to the array `[3,1,2]` by Postgres which is what a unique index uses.

This function can then be used for a unique index:

```
create unique index on my_table (non_null_values(my_table));
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ee6adb0edcddb86a653c1033eef0ebcd)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! When I try to run it, it fails with `PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  type my_table does not exist`

Comment: Well you need to use the real name of your table there.

Comment: Of course I did use it (and the column names of `p_row`)

Comment: Might it have something to do with the way talbe name is passed to the function? Should it be passed like `'my_table'::regclass` or something

Comment: You are not passing a table name to the function, you are passing a _row_ (record). See the online example

Comment: The issue I am having is caused by the fact that the table is defined in a non-public schema (`my_schema`): `my_db=# ALTER TABLE my_schema.my_table ADD CONSTRAINT all_unique CHECK ( all_unique(my_schema.my_table) );
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "my_schema"` - could you please advise on how to fix this one?

Comment: You just need to prefix everything properly: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9YM1syKUbMf3jYdMB3tabP/0 (press run once the page is loaded)

Comment: I see, the migration runs now, I wonder how you know that here: `ADD CONSTRAINT all_unique CHECK ( my_schema.all_unique(my_table)` you do not need to prefix the `my_table` with `my_schema`? What if there was `my_table` table in another schemas?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a fun constraint because of all the `NULL` values, but I think this does it;

```
alter table my_table add constraint chk_ugly check
     ( (col1 is null or col1 <> all (array_remove(array[col2, col3, col4, col5, col6], null))) and
       (col2 is null or col2 <> all (array_remove(array[col1, col3, col4, col5, col6], null))) and
       (col3 is null or col3 <> all (array_remove(array[col1, col2, col4, col5, col6], null))) and
       (col4 is null or col4 <> all (array_remove(array[col1, col2, col3, col5, col6], null))) and
       (col5 is null or col5 <> all (array_remove(array[col1, col2, col3, col4, col6], null))) and
       (col6 is null or col6 <> all (array_remove(array[col1, col2, col3, col4, col5], null))) 
     )
```

I do think there is a better way to structure your data, with one row per `col` and `id`.  That would be a new table.  That said, it would be hard to put a constraint on that mandating three values.

Note:  You existing constraint can be simplified in Postgres as well:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
    ADD CONSTRAINT my_constraint CHECK (
        cardinality(array_remove(array[col2, col3, col4, col5, col6], null)) >= 3
    )
```

Comment: The existing constraint can be simplified to Note the the current constraint can be simplified to `CHECK ( (num_nonnulls(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6) >= 3) )`

Comment: Thank you for the answer Gordon. I actually am currently having the structure with single row per col and id. My issue with this approach: multiple other tables have relation to this one (`other_table has_many my_table`) and I did not want to go with trigger constraints locking tables to check for min amount of related records upon each insert/delete. So I was sure this structure will ease that issue. + it is much easier to validate on the ORM level (because I validate fields of single record, rather then fields of 3 to 6 records). But I also wanted to ensure the integrity on the DB level ofc

Comment: `select 'foo' <> any (array['foo', 'bar']);` yields `t`, while it should be `f` I believe